# echo does not work for PATH variable!

Tags: perl

When I run the `ls` command this runs fine. But `echo $PATH` does not give me any output from perl. When I run `echo` from the shell prompt it gives me output. Can you explain this behavior?

```
#!usr/bin/perl

$\="\n";

$out = `ls`;
print $out;

$out=`echo $PATH`;
print $out;
```

Comment: If you had a "use strict" and "use warnings" in there you would have found out your error a lot sooner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that while the technically correct answer to your question is the `$` interpolation, you should also note that you should not treat Perl like a shell script and call external commands via backticks instead of using Perl built-in or library functions designed for the purpose:

```
$out = join("\n", glob("*")); # same as `ls`
$out = $ENV{PATH}; # same as `echo $PATH`
```

This has several significant advantages:

- speed (no call to system)
- portability
- More security (no shell attack vector)
- Most built ins cover proper error handling for you better than your own system call implementation
- Nearly always a better, cleaner, shorter and easier to read/maintain code

Comment: Much better than I tried to say in a comment to wk's answer. Further isn't the environment outside of your Perl script different than that seen from a system call? In this sense you gain no extra benefit from calling the system (to say learn about the environment variables "out there"), Perl has modified them. (Note: I say this to the OP, I know you know this DVK)

Answer (score 6):

Backticks [interpolate](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html) like double quotes, so you need to escape the `$`.

```
$out=`echo \$PATH`;
```

Comment: Or, as an alternative there is the generic quote operator qx that does not interpolate if ' is used as a delimiter: `$out = qx'echo $PATH';`.

Answer (score 5):

`$PATH` is shell variable, from perl you should use it as perl variable `$ENV{PATH}`

Still try to read some basic docs too, like [`perldoc perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html). No need for executing `echo` at all.

Comment: I'd upvote it if you wrote `echo $ENV{PATH}` (instead of just `$ENV{PATH}`) because this solution seems much cleaner to me than the escaping-stuff...

Comment: Yes you can interpolate the $ENV{PATH} into the `echo` command, but why not just use it in your script as `my $path = $ENV{'PATH'}; print $path;` What I think @eckes is suggesting (correct me if I'm wrong) is interpolating $ENV{'PATH'} into a system call to `echo`, capturing the return and then printing it, a highly circuitous way to access a value in a variable.

Comment: Just guessing, but I don't think the user really wants to run `echo`, it's probably just a placeholder for a more complicated command line.

Comment: @joel: that's why i told, there is no need for echo. At least in given context.

Comment: @mscha - can't read minds but IMHO the wording of the question suggests otherwise

Comment: This is why I really was commenting on eckes comment, since his/her comment explicitly says to do that. Perhaps I should have said that more clearly

Answer (score 1):

Perl is interpolating $PATH in the backticks as a Perl variable, and you've not set a $PATH anywhere in your script, so the command is coming out as

```
$out = `echo `
```

which is basically a null-op. Try

```
$out = `echo \$PATH`
```

instead, which would force Perl to ignore the $ and pass it intact to the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `$` in `$PATH` because the backticks operator interpolates any variables.

```
$out=`echo \$PATH`;
```

You could also use `qx//` with single quotes. From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> Using single-quote as a delimiter
>   protects the command from Perl's
>   double-quote interpolation, passing it
>   on to the shell instead:
>
> 1. $perl_info = qx(ps $$); # that's Perl's $$
> 2. $shell_info = qx'ps $$'; # that's the new shell's $$

Answer (score 1):

Others have already explained the reason - variables inside backticks are interpolated, so your `echo $PATH` is actually becoming `echo` since there's no `$PATH` variable declared.

However, *always* put `use strict;` at the top of every Perl script you write.

Had you done so, Perl would have told you what was happening, e.g.:

```
Global symbol "$PATH" requires explicit package name at myscript.pl line 9
```

To stop variables being interpolated, either escape them (e.g. `\$PATH`), or, more cleanly, use e.g. `qx'echo $PATH'`.

Also, as others have pointed out, calling `echo $PATH` makes no real-world sense; if you're trying to get the contents of the PATH environment variable, just use `$ENV{PATH}` - however, you may have just been using it as a simple reduced demonstration case.